Where does money come from when adding to apple account?
not super sure if this is the right place to ask the question, but I recently added $1 to my apple account balance as a test.
I originally thought nothing would happen, or it would tell me something is wrong with my payment methods.
Why? Because I only have one payment method, which is a Visa gift card. This gift card is basically empty if not completely, to the point where it gets declined no matter how small the price.
It might be important to note that I had previously added my debit card, (which I can't access the transaction history of because of technical difficulties) but I completely removed the payment method a long time ago. There's no trace on my apple account that it ever existed.
So back to me adding $1 to my apple account balance. I did this a couple days ago, through the apple app store. Although my Visa gift card always gets declined, (when purchasing things directly from the source online, like Robux from Roblox or tissues from Amazon) and my debit card had long since been erased from my apple ID, the transfer actually went through.
This leaves me wondering, "where did that $1 come from?" The reason why I'm so concerned is because even though I can't check my debit card history, I know that the money in it is $0.00 on the dot. I don't want a crazy overdraft fee over this simple test. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

The transfer will be reversed as soon as they realize the card was worthless.

It's possible that the card has $1.00 on the dot, but this $1.00 is usually unspendable due to $1.00 temporary holds.

The money comes from wherever you tell the folks running that service to take it from.
If you submit a bad transaction, it will be reversed. There may be a slight delay between the two so you may see the balance increase briefly, but it will go back down. If you spent it while it appeared to be there, your account will go negative and you will need to repay that plus whatever penalty fees and interest are described in the account's description (which you should have received a copy of, though you may not have bothered reading it).
In other words, it works like a checking account or prepaid credit card. If a deposit bounces, it bounces. Charging more to a gift card than the card can pay may appear to succeed at the moment, but that just acknowledges the transaction. As with check deposits, it does not mean that there is actual spendable money produced instantaneously; there is a reconciliation process between the banks which may take several days to complete. (Whether it should take that long has been opined on elsewhere.)
In fact many systems have a "funds pending" state specifically to allow for this, and will not let you actually spend the money until confirmation has completed, even if they show it in your balance.
Nihil ex nihil. No money is manufactured; it's an overdraft situation that will get fixed almost automatically unless you do something stupid like trying to spend money you don't have.
